# IVT and fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that
$f:[0,1]→[0,2]$
is continuous. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to
prove that there exists
$c∈[0,1]$
such that
$f(c)=2c^2$

The answer to this goes from the Fixed point theorem. But in that theorem the domain and codomain were the same but in this it is not. Here is what I did:

Define $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,2]$ by $g(x)=2x^2$. If $g(0)=0$ or $g(1)=2$ then we are done.

Otherwise, since $f(0),f(1) \in [0,2]$, $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<2$

Define $h:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,2]$ by $h(x)= 2x^2 - f(x)$. This is a continuous function. So $h(0)<0<h(1)$. By IVT, there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $h(c)=0$ giving the desired result.

Does this still work since the dom and codom of each function weren't the same. I know that for IVT, they dont have to be the same but for the ixed point theorem, it says they have to. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Your use of $f(x)$, since $f$ is given as an arbitrary continuous function, is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

If you want to *directly* use the fixed point theorem, note that we can define $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ by
$$
g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{2}}
$$
and that $g$ must have a fixed point.